# Assigning a date relative to another record's date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, relative-date

I'm building a Rails 4.2+ application that has `Workflows` and `Tasks`.  A `task.due_date` can either be a specified date (such as "01/01/2017") or it can be relative to a date on the parent `workflow` record.

```
class Workflow < ApplicationRecord
  # closing_date:date

  after_save :update_relative_tasks

  has_many :tasks

  # Production code would make sure closing_date changed before updating associations
  def update_relative_tasks
    tasks.where(has_relative_date: true).each do |task|
      task.update_relative_due_date(closing_date)
    end
  end
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  # due_date:date
  # has_relative_date:boolean (default: false)
  # number:integer (default: 0)
  # days_or_weeks:string (default: "days")
  # before_or_after:string (default: "after")
  # workflow:references

  belongs_to :workflow

  def number_of_days
    @number_of_days ||= if days_or_weeks == "weeks"
      number * 7 # relative date is in "weeks"
    else
      number # assume relative date is in "days"
    end
  end

  # Pseudo-ish code, not tested, but shows concept
  def update_relative_due_date(date)
    new_due_date = if before_or_after == "before"
      date - number_of_days.days
    else
      date + number_of_days.days
    end

   update_attribute(:due_date, new_due_date)
  end
end
```

Assigning a specific date on the `task` is simple, I just use a calendar widget and it sets the date, no problem.

The tricky part is assigning a relative `task.due_date` based off of the `workflow.closing_date`.

For example, let's say the `workflow.closing_date` is `01/01/2017` and I want to have a task due 5 days before (or after) that date.

I can add some form fields that do something like, where the brackets represent input fields:

```
Due Date: [x] number of [days|weeks] [before|after] workflow.closing_date
```

and then I can parse that out in Ruby code and update the `task` with the proper `due_date`.

However, if the `workflow.closing_date` changes, I then would need to go find all the associated `tasks` and re-calculate their relative dates. Also, if the `workflow.closing_date` wasn't known initially and it was added later on, it would again need to re-calculate the due dates for all associated tasks.

Eventually I'm also going to add reminders to `tasks`, and those also will be relative to the `task.due_date`.  Very similar to how Google Calendar's notifications work.

How is something like this solved?  I know I'll need to add a background processor to handle sending reminders.  But I'm uncertain how to solve the issue of setting a `task.due_date` relative to some date on another record.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing the difficulty in this issue so will try to talk through it. Could you set an after_save filter on workflow to handle any changes to related object if the workflow is saved?

**workflow.rb**

```
after_save :update_due_date

def update_due_date
   self.tasks.update_all(due_date: self.closing_date + 5.days)
end
```

This way the tasks closing dates are always relative to the workflows closing_date and you don't have to worry about complicated update logic. Maybe I missed something above..

Comment: The issue is that each `task` may have a different `due_date`, so I can't bulk update them.  That's the reason I was doing the complicated calculations.  Also, I wanted to have a clean interface for non-techy users to put in the relative values, so I think I would have to do some sort of conversion from "x days after this date" into the actual calculated due_date.